# Upload data from shiny dashboard and download R markdown html file with select input in html file

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, markdown, shinydashboard, shinyapps

How to download R markdown html file report with select input in the html file once the  user uploads a data in to the shiny and click on Generate Report the User will be able to download data table out put inside the html file But I am not able insert select input inside the html Report to see the dynamic selections inside the data tables.

****Shiny Dashboard****

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    fileInput("csvFile", "Input Data"),
    
    
    actionButton("refreshPlot", "Update preferences",
                 
                 style = "color: #fff; background-color: #39A2DB; border-color: #fff;padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; "),
    
    downloadButton("report", "Generate report",
                   
                   style = "color: #fff; background-color: #27ae60; border-color: #fff;padding: 5px 14px 5px 14px;margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px; ")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    box(
      uiOutput("Cars_data"),
      
      dataTableOutput("mtcares_data")
      
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data_1<-eventReactive(input$refreshPlot,{
    
    file1 <- input$csvFile
    if (is.null(file1)) { 
      return() 
    } 
    data = read.csv(file=file1$datapath)
    
  })
  
  output$mtcares_data<-renderDataTable({
    
    data.frame(data_1()[input$Cars])

  })

  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    # For PDF output, change this to "report.pdf"
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      # Copy the report file to a temporary directory before processing it, in
      # case we don't have write permissions to the current working dir (which
      # can happen when deployed).
      tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "report.Rmd")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
      params <- list(n = data_1()[input$Cars]
                     
                     
      ) 
      # Knit the document, passing in the `params` list, and eval it in a
      # child of the global environment (this isolates the code in the document
      # from the code in this app).
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
    
  )
  
  output$Cars_data<-renderUI({
        selectInput("Cars", "Habitent Transformations",choices=names(data_1()))
    
  })
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Report**

````
    ---
title: "Dynamic report"
output: html_document
params:
  n: NA
---

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}
res<-data.frame(params$n)
   datatable(res,options = list(
  dom = 't',
  scrollX = TRUE,
  scrollCollapse = TRUE
))
````

[image]

**project file to download **

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nCY_X6P-ebQwUXOstrq2vB5yC_R8CPpy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is the R Markdown file in the same directory as your Shiny script? If not, check if the file path.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.